# file_get_contents equivalent of curl function

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I have following curl program which is working fine.

```
$data="var1=$var1&var2=$var2";  
$ch = curl_init("http://www.website.asmx/FetchData");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

I tried following code to get same data using file_get_contents but it returns false.

```
$data="var1=$var1&var2=$var2";  
$result = file_get_contents("http://www.website.asmx/FetchData?=".$data);
var_dump($result);
exit();
```

What code will be equivalent to above curl program?

Comment: Delete the **=** within the Line: **.../FetchData?=" . $data);** That is the Bug...  It should read: **.../FetchData?" . $data);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the **=** at the End of FetchData in:

```
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.website.asmx/FetchData?=".$data));
```

This should rather read:

```
//WITHOUT THE EQUAL SIGN AFTER FetchData...
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.website.asmx/FetchData?".$data));
```